# How to classify an customer's order based on its contents

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have a table of order lines, e.g.

```
(Order ID, Product ID, Qty, Product Type)   

(Order1 , SKU123 , 1 , Pen)

(Order2 , SKU234 , 1 , Pencil)

(Order3 , SKU123 , 2 , Pen)

(Order3 , SKU234 , 2 , Pencil)
```

...and I want to roll these up and classify them at Order ID level, so...

```
(Order ID, Order Type)

(Order1 , "Pen order")

(Order2 , "Pencil order")

(Order3 , "Mixed order")
```

Is there an elegant way of getting to this result? There could be as many as 25 Product Types.

Open to SQL, DAX or native Power BI solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DAX,

```
SUMMARIZE (
    Orders,
    Orders[Order ID],
    "Order Type", SELECTEDVALUE ( Orders[Product Type], "Mixed" ) & " order"
)
```

The [`SELECTEDVALUE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) returns the `Product Type` if there is a single one and the alternate result "Mixed" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For this example, you can use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select orderid,
       (case when min(producttype) = max(producttype) then concat(min(producttype), ' Order')
             else 'Mixed Order'
        end) as order_type
from orderlines ol
group by orderid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by your order and count number of distinct product type. If there is more than 1 product type then you can show 'Mixed Order'

```
select 
    OrderID, 
    (Case 
        when Count(distinct ProductID) > 1 then 'Mixed Order' 
        else min(ProductType) + ' Order' 
    End) AS OrderType
from OrderDetails
group by OrderID
```